# Fullscreen ProgressBar on WearOS

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm trying to get a `ProgressBar` that goes around the edge of the entire screen on a WearOS watch, like this:

[image]

I thought having a layout like this would work but this just makes a big `ProgressBar` in the center of the screen:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
            
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Large"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Update

I found you can use a `layer-list` to change the size of the `ProgressBar`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
 
          <shape
                android:radius="18dp"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thickness="2dp"
                android:useLevel="true">
            </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

If you could programmatically set `android:radius` to the size of the screen, it might work. Something like this:

```
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
gradientDrawable.setInnerRadius(18);
((ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress_bar)).setProgressDrawable(gradientDrawable);
```

Comment: Can you use a top level FrameLayout for this? and have the ProgressBar match_parent?

Comment: I spent more time on this and you can get the `ProgressBar` to go to the edge of the screen by assigning a `layer-list` drawable to the `ProgressBar` and adding a `shape` node to the drawable then setting the `android:radius` attribute to the screen size but it was too much work to figure out how to do it programmatically. Need to use a `GradientDrawable`. I'll update my question with what I have.

Answer (score 1):

This is a circular progress indicator right?
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/compose/progress-indicator

[image: circular progress indicator with gap]

```
CircularProgressIndicator(
    progress = 0.4f,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    startAngle = 10f,
    endAngle = 290f,
    strokeWidth = 4.dp
)
```

Comment: Yes but it's only for Compose and I'm using XML Views. Compose wasn't available when I built my app unfortunately.

Comment: You can extend AbstractComposeView to bridge between the two

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/AbstractComposeView