# Full screen CircularProgressIndicator blocks the touch within a FrameLayout

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have implemented stopwatch with CircularProgressIndicator with a full screen that only appears on the edges. so CircularProgressIndicator overlays MainLayout and blocks all the clicks within this layout. I have tried to set `android:clickable="false"` on CircularProgressIndicator and android:clickable="true on layout below. But none of the variations worked for me. How can I make this working?

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="start" android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            app:layout_box="all"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:background="#FFFFFF">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs" android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />

            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/MainPager" android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout>
 
    
    <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" android:clickable="false"
        android:id="@+id/timerProgress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"        
        android:indeterminate="false"
        app:trackThickness="2dp"
        app:indicatorColor="@color/green"
        app:trackColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:tooltipText="Loading"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/green"      
           />
</FrameLayout>
```

EDIT: what I tried to achieve is the screenshot on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70404550/fullscreen-progressbar-on-wearos) post. UI is perfectly fine and looks similar to below but as I have the CircularProgressIndicator as the last control within the Framelayout it blocks the controls below. If I add it as first element in FL, this time CircularProgressIndicator is not visible at all.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is because your `CircularProgressIndicator` is above all your content so every click will be into your `CircularProgressIndicator` view. I don't know what are you trying to do, but you can set an `onClickListener` to you `CirculerProgressIndicator` or readjust your layout in a way that your `CircularProgressIndicator` will be by side of your other components, and not above.

Comment: yes, thats clear that it is above all but If i set clickable=false and control below to true, it should pass the click event to the control below. I dont get why it doesnt work. There are many SO posts suggesting it.
it is not possible to have CircularProgressIndicator. I will update my question but basically what i tried to achieve is like on this post screen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70404550/fullscreen-progressbar-on-wearos

Comment: Hmm thanks for posting the image. You said "If I add it as first element in FL, this time CircularProgressIndicator is not visible at all." I think that would be the best approach, maybe one of your views have an opaque background. Have you already verified it using the Layout Inspector tool from Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to place `CircularProgressIndicator`  on the bottom ,and then place BoxInsetLayout with a transparent background above it .

But here is a tricky way , we can create a subclass inherit from `CircularProgressIndicator`  , and override the method `OnInterceptTouchEvent`.

```
 public class MyControl : CircularProgressIndicator
    {
        public MyControl (Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And then add the custom control into parent layout in code

```
MyControl a= new MyControl(this);
a.LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent);
parent.AddView(a, 1);
```

Then the clicked event should be triggered on `BoxInsetLayout`.